# JavaScript to validate password

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, unicode, passwords

Can anyone help me in writing a regular expression on the following description?

The password contains characters from at least three of the following five categories:

- English uppercase characters (A - Z)
- English lowercase characters (a - z)
- Base 10 digits (0 - 9)
- Non-alphanumeric (For example: !, $, #, or %)
- Unicode characters

The minimum length of the password is 6.

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP is not looking to create a Javascript-based login, but a simple validation when the user specifies the password.

Comment: Some old comments about pseudo-strong passwords: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/07/passwords-vs-pass-phrases.html

Comment: That's not a simple task for a regular expression. As Sachin is proposing in his anser, it would be easier to write your own string parsing routine and count if your criteria are matching.

Comment: Don't forget to validate in server side code as well. JavaScript is easily disableable and spoofable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better way to deal this is to split each of the conditions and have a regex for each of the condition. Then count how many have been satisfied for entered password. In this way you can even tell user if the password is average, meets criteria or a very strong password.

```
if (password.length < 6) {
  alert("password needs to be atleast 6 characters long"); 
}

var count = 0;
//UpperCase
if( /[A-Z]/.test(password) ) {
    count += 1;
}
//Lowercase
if( /[a-z]/.test(password) ) {
    count += 1;
}
//Numbers  
if( /\d/.test(password) ) {
    count += 1;
} 
//Non alphas( special chars)
if( /\W/.test(password) ) {
    count += 1;
}
if (count < 3) {
  alert("password does not match atleast 3 criterias"); 
}
```

Not sure how to match unicode characters using regex. Rest all conditions are available above.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. (Completely agree, btw.)

Answer (score 1):

`[A-Za-z!$#%\d\u0100]{6}` matches `aS1%eĀ`.

`\u0100` is for Ā. You can insert other Unicode codes that you need. You can find them [here](http://inamidst.com/stuff/unidata/).

EDIT: For minimum 6 characters the correct regex is `[A-Za-z!$#%\d\u0100]{6,}`.

EDIT 2: To include a range of Unicode characters (let that be Latin Extended-B), the regex should look like `^[A-Za-z!$#%\d\u0100-\u017f]{6,}$`. You can find the Unicode code ranges [here](http://inamidst.com/stuff/unidata/).

EDIT 3: I've developed a tiny function that checks whether the given password conforms to the criterias. You need to define the unicode range in the function.

```
function isValidPassword(password) {    
    var unicodeRange = "\\u0100-\\u0105";
    var criteria = ["A-Z","a-z","\\d","!$#%",unicodeRange];

    // check whether it doesn't include other characters
    var re = new RegExp("^[" + criteria.join("") +"]{6,}$");
    if(!re.test(password)) return false;

    var minSatisfiedCondition = 3;
    var satisfiedCount = 0;
    for( var i=0; i < criteria.length; i++) {
      re = new RegExp("[" + criteria[i] + "]");
      if(re.test(password)) ++satisfiedCount;

    }
    return (satisfiedCount >= minSatisfiedCondition);
}​
```

There is a working sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WKswx/).

Comment: With this regular expressions you don't know if at least 3 criteria of the OP are matching.

Comment: @splash: Yes, you're right. I've edited my answer and put a validation function.